# Partition Insertion Issue while inserting data

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition, filegroup

I have table ABC in Oracle which has partition b100 and b200 which holds data like 100 and 200 accordingly. When we try to insert data apart from these Oracle developer throws an error.

Now when we try to implement the same thing in SQL SERVER, the data apart from these partion values are also getting inserted in the table. So how to restrict the unpartitioned from Insertion

In SQL SERVER the unpartitioned data is getting into PRIMARY filegroup or the last filegroup. Which we are not expecting

Comment: Please add sql-server table definition as text with sample insert statements which prove your assertion. PS I have deleted the irrelevant MYSQL tag.

Comment: It is always better to show us a Schema for the tables you are asking about rather than a few sentences, then there is no confusion or ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server table partitioning is natively range partitioning and does not constrain data. There is always a partition for every possible partitioning column value.

Use a `CHECK` constraint (or alternatively a `FOREIGN KEY`) to limit values that can be inserted into the table. These can be the same as the partition boundaries to effectively implement partitioning on an exact list of values instead of range.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourPartitionedTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_YourPartitionedTable_YourPartitioningColumn
    CHECK (YourPartitioningColumn IN (100,200));
```

The last partition will always be empty in the case of a `RANGE LEFT` partition function. Conversely, the first partition will be empty with a `RANGE RIGHT` function.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i tried this implementation. The problem is if the insertion script finds any values apart for 100 and 200 it's just terminating the query with an error about constraints

Comment: @manjunathkurabar, I thought you wanted that behavior - an error if the inserted value doesn't match the partition boundary value. What behavior do you expect?